# Using htaccess, how to redirect all sub-domain URLS that are not www to same sub-domain URL on new domain?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

For example:

If the sub-domain URL is not www.domain.com/something but is instead something like:

sub.domain.com/something then redirect it to sub.new-domain.com/something

The trick, for me, is (a) only redirecting if it's not www and (b) redirecting to same subdomain and path but on a new domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.new-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The condition checks to see if the URL doesn't have www. If it does, then it will not proceed further.

If the URL `http://sub.domain.com/something` was entered, it would change to `http://sub.new-domain.com/something`. But if the URL was `http://www.sub.domain.com/something` the rule would not pass.

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

**// EDIT BASED ON COMMENT //**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.new-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Based on your comment, I've now updated the rule. This now includes two conditions, the first grabs your random subdomain and the second condition is to check for the presence of www.

`%1` used in the rewrite grabs the random subdomain and appends it to the new URL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have clarified that the subdomain is dynamic. There are dozens of different subdomains so whichever one is accessed would need to dynamically redirect to that same subdomain and path, but on the new domain name.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply @quantumized ! Please try my edit based off of your comment. This should do exactly what you need :)

Comment: Thanks a ton! Your solution worked perfectly. I was racking my brain trying to get it to work by trial and error - without luck.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad I could help :) htaccess can be a bit of a nightmare at times.